# How to update/replace robots.txt file in aws cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-crawler, amazon-cloudfront, google-search, robots.txt

I have a website `www.example.com`. So when I access robots.txt file like `www.example.com/robots.txt` and it shows multiple lines text which is created/prepared by SEO team.

So there is a sub domain `assets.example.com` which is pointing to CloudFront. When I access the robots.txt file through CloudFront URL like `https://assets.example.com/robtos.txt` then it shows below result in the browser.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

So there is a request to update the robots.txt file content in AWS CloudFront so `https://assets.example.com/robtos.txt` & `https://www.example.com/robtos.txt` should show the same text. I didn't find anywhere robots.txt is placed in cloud-front.

Is it possible to update robots.txt in cloudfront? Is there any role of CloudFront here? Or we need to update the robots.txt for assets.example.com same as configured for example.com?

Please help me out. I'm very confused here.

Comment: What's the origin of `assets.example.com`?

Comment: In route53 ```assets.example.com``` is pointing to CloudFront and that CloudFront  is pointing to S3 bucket. So S3 will be origin server. Actually I didn't this setup I'm new in the current organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point the CloudFront distribution (assets.example.com), then add a new origin with the domain name `www.example.com` then add a new cache behavior with the path pattern `robots.txt` and add the origin to it.

This setup takes a request to `assets.example.com/robots.txt` and forwards it to `www.example.com/robots.txt`. With this, you can remove the duplications.

Answer (score 1):

You can invalidate cached by option invalidation.

You can do following :

1. Directly deploy build folder to S3 bucket.
2. Not required to cached `robots.txt` file
3. Whenever you deployed or upload build to S3,do the following step
4. Go to cloudfront
5. Do invalidation of objects
6. Create entry /*

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was solved by invalidating the file which was not being updated /robots.txt